# Replacing linefeeds but not \n in a variable (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

In this case, I want to replace linefeeds(\n) to @ but not \n used inside the variable.
Are there any ways to distinguish linefeeds from \n inside the code?

For example, I don't want to replace \n inside this: alert("abc \n cde")

```
let my_code = `
    alert("abc \n cde");
    alert("efd \n hij");
    alert("klm \n opq");
    alert("stu \n vwx");
`;
console.log( my_code )
my_code = my_code.replace(/\n/g, '@');
console.log( my_code )
```

online code editor: https://jsfiddle.net/r6La9mz2/

Comment: The premise of this question seems wrong here; your `my_code` string has linefeeds. It doesn't have any backslashes or `n` characters in it (`console.log(my_code.includes("n"))` produces `false` even before you reassign it).   There is no difference between the linefeeds you include literally and the ones you include via escape sequence.  What are you really trying to do?  Could you change your original string so that it has backslashes in it?

Comment: In this case, I was making an online code editor.
It worked well but couldn't treat the \n inside the code properly.
I can't change the original string beforehand. But thanks for asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Once you use `\n` in string literal or string template it is parsed the same way you'd "pressed enter" there:

```
`#
#` === `#\n#` // true
```

---

In your particular use-case/example it may help to replace only all *newlines not preceded by a space* (`/(?<! )\n/g`) sequences, provided the "real" newlines are not also preceded by spaces.

```
`a \n b
c \n d`.replace(/(?<! )\n/g,'@') 
===
`a 
 b@c 
 d` // true
```

Comment: Please, remove that recommendation. It's not a good idea. If someone copies your solution, it will look like the problem was solved. While it is just harder to detect.
(in particular it didn't solve the OPs use-case, as according to his comment he is using it in an editor)

Answer (score 2):

"\n" is a line-feed.
If you want to write \n (a backslash and an 'n') in a string, you have to write "\\n", and thus

```
console.log("abc \\n cde".replace(/\n/g, '@'));
```

will output

abc \n cde